# How to use proxy in Wi-fi setting for the app in Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, proxy

Case:
I use Flutter to create an app, and the app will call Restful Api to backend server to get data.
However, the backend server only open to a selected host and port for security reason.
The app works well if it is under that network, but cannot works properly because of fail to get data if out of that network.
As a result, I would like to setup a proxy for the wi-fi I'm using, and run the app as normal.
Unfortunately, the flutter app still not working in both Android and IOS platform.

Question:
How to use proxy in Wi-fi setting for the app in Flutter app?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using this package to apply the system's global proxy settings: https://pub.dev/packages/native_flutter_proxy

Dart's networking tools don't pick up these settings on their own.